# .htaccess rewrite rule is not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have .htaccess file in same folder where my code resides.

```
# Turn rewrite engine on
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/mobile/list/$ RestController.php?view=all [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/mobile/list/([0-9]+)/$ RestController.php?view=single&id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Rewritebase added as per hosting provider (https://www.hostinger.in/knowledge-base/489) But my rewrites are not working if i try to load the url

jobstatuscheck.esy.es/mobile/list/

It is not redirecting to jobstatuscheck.esy.es/RestController.php?view=all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `RewriteRule` works on a *relative* path, not on an *absolute* path, when used inside a dynamic configuration file. That is because those files are interpreted relative to their location in the document hierarchy. This is clearly pointed out in the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) of Apache's rewriting module.

That means you need to either use relative paths in your patterns or a somewhat more flexible approach (note the additional question marks...):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/?mobile/list/?$ RestController.php?view=all [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/?mobile/list/([0-9]+)/?$ RestController.php?view=single&id=$1 [NC,L]
```

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers (virtual) host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (`.htaccess` style files). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only supported as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).